# Database connecion with qt to phpmyadmin

Tags: c++, database, qt, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm developping a desktop application with QT(C++) and i need to connect this application to a database created with wamp(phpmyadmin) and this is my code :

```
static bool createConnexion()
{
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("");
db.setDatabaseName("compagnie");
if(db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "Vous etes connecte a " << db.hostName();
    return true;



 }else{
    qDebug() << "Connexion FAILED.";
    qDebug() << "Driver disponible: " << db.drivers();
    qDebug() << "Driver fonctionnel(QMYSQL): " << db.isDriverAvailable("QSQLITE");
    qDebug() << "numero de l'erreur: " << db.lastError().number();
    qDebug() << "database erreur: " << db.lastError().databaseText();
    qDebug() << "driver erreur: " << db.lastError().driverText();
    qDebug() << "type erreur: " << db.lastError().type();
    return true;
   }

}
```

and the error is : driver not loaded.
is there a solution to resolve this and i searched for driver for phpmyadmin but still i can't find it.
      Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");` - so a SQLite database, but do not supply a db-file ( SQLite thing ) , I believe you are looking for the MYSQL connection type: `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");`

Comment: I did try that but still same error.

Comment: then you most likely forgot to add the sql-driver plugins, have a look here: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19519

Comment: thanks for the fast responses but still no i applied both solutuion. here's the error : QSqlDatabase: MYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC